# Ajax calls return 404 in Google Cloud Platform - works fine locally?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-cloud-platform

I forked this [great repo](http://www.javarepl.com/term.html) which provides a Java repl, in the browser. I deployed it as a Google Cloud app, so that it could enjoy some https sweetness.

I am nearly there:

https://repl.clementlevallois.net/embed.html

... except that the ajax calls made by [term.js](https://repl.clementlevallois.net/ui/term.js) return a 404, and this breaks the session mechanism. It works fine locally.

I am a Java developper and a js noob - is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you started `javarepl-SOME_VERSION.jar` on your server?

Comment: Not exactly sure... It is a jar (packaged as a war) with a main class so I assumed it was... (the java repl is included as a maven dependency)

Comment: Yes, it has, but you need to start it, so that program will be able to respond to HTTP requests. Right now a call to `https://repl.clementlevallois.net/create` fails, it means the server doesn't handle that request. See [the documentation](https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl#usage).

Comment: Ok so I changed the page so that it launches the jar when it loads: 
https://repl.clementlevallois.net/embedded.jsp
still no luck.

Comment: What do you see in your app's logs in the developer console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was due to calls being made to a server spinned by the app, listening on a different port than 8080. This is not allowed.